# Python, Flask, MongoDB Deployment in Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, flask

Ive been trying to deploy my python project at heroku but it seems like I'm getting this "cannot import name function" error. This is my requirements.txt

```
Flask==0.10.1
Flask-PyMongo==0.3.0
Flask-RESTful==0.2.12
Jinja2==2.7.3
MarkupSafe==0.23
Werkzeug==0.9.6
aniso8601==0.82
gunicorn==19.0.0
itsdangerous==0.24
pymongo==2.7.1
pytz==2014.4
six==1.7.2
dj-static==0.0.6
django==1.7
```

And here's my error log

```
2016-06-10T07:29:52.397611+00:00 app[web.1]:     def __getattr__(self, name):
2016-06-10T07:29:52.397673+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 209, in handle_chld
2016-06-10T07:29:52.397928+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.reap_workers()
2016-06-10T07:29:52.397949+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 459, in reap_workers
2016-06-10T07:29:52.398259+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2016-06-10T07:29:52.398291+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2016-06-10T07:29:53.359165+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2016-06-10T07:29:53.345943+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-06-10T07:34:00.489059+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-06-10T07:34:00.489063+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2016-06-10T07:34:00.313413+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy d682ad2 by it.africaken@gmail.com
2016-06-10T07:34:00.313510+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v13 created by it.africaken@gmail.com
2016-06-10T07:34:00.492850+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-06-10T07:34:05.125268+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn app:app --log-file -`
2016-06-10T07:34:06.749636+00:00 app[web.1]: 2016-06-10 07:34:06 [3] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.0.0
2016-06-10T07:34:06.750456+00:00 app[web.1]: 2016-06-10 07:34:06 [3] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:44191 (3)
2016-06-10T07:34:06.750623+00:00 app[web.1]: 2016-06-10 07:34:06 [3] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2016-06-10T07:34:06.753888+00:00 app[web.1]: 2016-06-10 07:34:06 [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
2016-06-10T07:34:06.835187+00:00 app[web.1]: 2016-06-10 07:34:06 [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
2016-06-10T07:34:07.012481+00:00 app[web.1]: 2016-06-10 07:34:07 [8] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
2016-06-10T07:34:07.012491+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2016-06-10T07:34:07.012492+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 502, in spawn_worker
2016-06-10T07:34:07.012493+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2016-06-10T07:34:07.012494+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 114, in init_process
2016-06-10T07:34:07.012495+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2016-06-10T07:34:07.012496+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 66, in wsgi
2016-06-10T07:34:07.012496+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2016-06-10T07:34:07.012497+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
2016-06-10T07:34:07.012498+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
2016-06-10T07:34:07.012498+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2016-06-10T07:34:07.012499+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2016-06-10T07:34:07.012500+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 356, in import_app
2016-06-10T07:34:07.012500+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2016-06-10T07:34:07.012501+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
2016-06-10T07:34:07.012502+00:00 app[web.1]:     from app import views
2016-06-10T07:34:07.012502+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app/views.py", line 3, in <module>
2016-06-10T07:34:07.012503+00:00 app[web.1]:     from app import func
2016-06-10T07:34:07.012503+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: cannot import name 'func'
2016-06-10T07:34:07.012504+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2016-06-10T07:34:07.012506+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 114, in init_process
2016-06-10T07:34:07.012505+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 502, in spawn_worker
2016-06-10T07:34:07.012505+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2016-06-10T07:34:07.012506+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2016-06-10T07:34:07.012507+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 66, in wsgi
2016-06-10T07:34:07.012508+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2016-06-10T07:34:07.012509+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
2016-06-10T07:34:07.012509+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2016-06-10T07:34:07.012510+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
2016-06-10T07:34:07.012511+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2016-06-10T07:34:07.012511+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 356, in import_app
2016-06-10T07:34:07.012512+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2016-06-10T07:34:07.012513+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
2016-06-10T07:34:07.012513+00:00 app[web.1]:     from app import views
2016-06-10T07:34:07.012514+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app/views.py", line 3, in <module>
2016-06-10T07:34:07.012515+00:00 app[web.1]:     from app import func
2016-06-10T07:34:07.012519+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: cannot import name 'func'
2016-06-10T07:34:07.012799+00:00 app[web.1]: 2016-06-10 07:34:07 [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
2016-06-10T07:34:07.013503+00:00 app[web.1]: 2016-06-10 07:34:07 [7] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
2016-06-10T07:34:07.013505+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2016-06-10T07:34:07.013506+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 502, in spawn_worker
2016-06-10T07:34:07.013507+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2016-06-10T07:34:07.013508+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 114, in init_process
2016-06-10T07:34:07.013509+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2016-06-10T07:34:07.013510+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 66, in wsgi
2016-06-10T07:34:07.013510+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2016-06-10T07:34:07.013511+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
2016-06-10T07:34:07.013512+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2016-06-10T07:34:07.013512+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
2016-06-10T07:34:07.013513+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2016-06-10T07:34:07.013514+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 356, in import_app
2016-06-10T07:34:07.013514+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2016-06-10T07:34:07.013515+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
2016-06-10T07:34:07.013516+00:00 app[web.1]:     from app import views
2016-06-10T07:34:07.013516+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app/views.py", line 3, in <module>
2016-06-10T07:34:07.013517+00:00 app[web.1]:     from app import func
2016-06-10T07:34:07.013517+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: cannot import name 'func'
2016-06-10T07:34:07.013518+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2016-06-10T07:34:07.013519+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 502, in spawn_worker
2016-06-10T07:34:07.013519+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2016-06-10T07:34:07.013520+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 114, in init_process
2016-06-10T07:34:07.013520+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2016-06-10T07:34:07.013521+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 66, in wsgi
2016-06-10T07:34:07.013522+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2016-06-10T07:34:07.013522+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
2016-06-10T07:34:07.013523+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2016-06-10T07:34:07.013524+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
2016-06-10T07:34:07.013524+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2016-06-10T07:34:07.013525+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 356, in import_app
2016-06-10T07:34:07.013526+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2016-06-10T07:34:07.013526+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
2016-06-10T07:34:07.013527+00:00 app[web.1]:     from app import views
2016-06-10T07:34:07.013528+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app/views.py", line 3, in <module>
2016-06-10T07:34:07.013528+00:00 app[web.1]:     from app import func
2016-06-10T07:34:07.013529+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: cannot import name 'func'
2016-06-10T07:34:07.013832+00:00 app[web.1]: 2016-06-10 07:34:07 [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
2016-06-10T07:34:07.165870+00:00 app[web.1]: 2016-06-10 07:34:07 [3] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2016-06-10T07:34:07.165961+00:00 app[web.1]: 2016-06-10 07:34:07 [3] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2016-06-10T07:34:07.879876+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2016-06-10T07:34:07.897261+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-06-10T07:34:07.898032+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-06-10T07:34:13.233806+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn app:app --log-file -`
2016-06-10T07:34:15.259167+00:00 app[web.1]: 2016-06-10 07:34:15 [3] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.0.0
2016-06-10T07:34:15.259617+00:00 app[web.1]: 2016-06-10 07:34:15 [3] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:12266 (3)
2016-06-10T07:34:15.259714+00:00 app[web.1]: 2016-06-10 07:34:15 [3] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2016-06-10T07:34:15.262537+00:00 app[web.1]: 2016-06-10 07:34:15 [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
2016-06-10T07:34:15.283985+00:00 app[web.1]: 2016-06-10 07:34:15 [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513270+00:00 app[web.1]: 2016-06-10 07:34:15 [8] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513282+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513283+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 502, in spawn_worker
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513284+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513285+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 114, in init_process
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513285+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513286+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 66, in wsgi
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513286+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513287+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513288+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513288+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513289+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513290+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 356, in import_app
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513290+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513291+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513292+00:00 app[web.1]:     from app import views
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513293+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app/views.py", line 3, in <module>
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513293+00:00 app[web.1]:     from app import func
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513294+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: cannot import name 'func'
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513294+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513295+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 502, in spawn_worker
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513296+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513296+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 114, in init_process
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513297+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513298+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 66, in wsgi
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513298+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513299+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513299+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513300+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513300+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513301+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 356, in import_app
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513301+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513301+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513302+00:00 app[web.1]:     from app import views
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513302+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app/views.py", line 3, in <module>
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513303+00:00 app[web.1]:     from app import func
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513303+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: cannot import name 'func'2016-06-10 07:34:15 [7] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513304+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513304+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 502, in spawn_worker
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513304+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513305+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 114, in init_process
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513305+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513305+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 66, in wsgi
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513306+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513306+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513306+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513307+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513307+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513307+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 356, in import_app
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513308+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513308+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513308+00:00 app[web.1]:     from app import views
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513309+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app/views.py", line 3, in <module>
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513309+00:00 app[web.1]:     from app import func
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513309+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: cannot import name 'func'
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513310+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513310+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 502, in spawn_worker
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513310+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513311+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 114, in init_process
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513311+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513311+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 66, in wsgi
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513312+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513312+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513312+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513313+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513313+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513313+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 356, in import_app
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513314+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513314+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513317+00:00 app[web.1]:     from app import views
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513318+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app/views.py", line 3, in <module>
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513318+00:00 app[web.1]:     from app import func
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513319+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: cannot import name 'func'
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513319+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513584+00:00 app[web.1]: 2016-06-10 07:34:15 [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
2016-06-10T07:34:15.513593+00:00 app[web.1]: 2016-06-10 07:34:15 [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
2016-06-10T07:34:16.822551+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2016-06-10T07:34:45.648883+00:00 app[web.1]: 2016-06-10 07:34:45 [3] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2016-06-10T07:34:45.648999+00:00 app[web.1]: 2016-06-10 07:34:45 [3] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2016-06-10T07:34:46.379088+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2016-06-10T07:34:46.392916+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

I've tried changing versions as some thread in here says and also adding kombu on the requirements.txt

This is my views.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from app import app
from app import func

apicall = func.func()

@app.route("/", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def indexd():
        tdl = apicall.selDB()
        return render_template("index.html", act=acts)

@app.route('/index')
def index():
        return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/edit')
def edit():
        return render_template('edit.html')

@app.route("/insDB", methods=["POST"])
def callInsert():
        tdl  = request.form['var']
        return apicall.insDB(tdl)
        #return redirect(url_for('edit'))

@app.route("/selDB", methods=["POST"])
def callSelect():
        tdl  = request.form['var']
        return apicall.selDB(tdl)

@app.route("/delDB", methods=["POST"])
def callDelete():
        tdl  = request.form['var']
        return apicall.delDB(tdl)

@app.route("/updDB", methods=["POST"])
def callUpdate():
        tdl  = request.form['var']
        return apicall.updDB(tdl)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Project tree:

```
pytodo/
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   ├── run.py
│   ├── static
│   ├── templates
│   └── views.py
├── flask
│   ├── Include
│   ├── Lib
│   ├── pip-selfcheck.json
│   ├── Scripts
│   └── tcl
├── Procfile
├── requirements.txt
├── run.py
└── runtime.txt
```

Comment: Please post your project tree and the contents of app/views.py. Thank you

Comment: What does this have to do with flask (or django?) or ruby-on-rails?

Comment: I thought that they have something to do with the error since im using them.

Comment: @MohammadAmin i have added my views.py

Comment: Your problem is simple. Instead of all that long log and requirements file, you should post your app file contents. Apparently python can't import func from your app. We'll need a tree view of the files and folders.

Comment: @MohammadAmin posted. Sorry for the wait

Comment: Is func in your app/__init__.py?

Comment: A new error appeared

Comment: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>

Comment: And what is in your app/__init__.py ?

Comment: from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
from app import views

Comment: Then in file views.py, what is from app import func?

Comment: Im trying to import functions from an external file which is func.py